# Homology of blow-ups of $P^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

$M_1$ and $M_2$ are both blowups of $\mathbb P^n$  at a finite number of points and linear subspaces.   Suppose   $M_1$ and $M_2$ have the same homology (over $\mathbb Q$), then do we know $M_1$ and $M_2$ are homeomorphic?

In other words, can we find two different sequences of blowups of $\mathbb P^n$ at points and linear subspaces, such that they are homologous?

Comment: This is not true. The blow up of $\mathbb{CP}^3$ in a line and a point have the same Betti numbers, but they are not homeomorphic because their cohomology rings are not isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you, Nick!    May I ask a further question: $M_1, M_2$ as above, if we know they have isomorphic cohomology rings, do we know they are homologous?    Equivariant cohomology is strong enough to distinguish toric (of course homeomorphic) structures, and I wonder how much information we have from cohomology rings, provided manifolds are birational to $P^n$?